# Variable invalidated after CTRL+Z

Tags: python, scripting, matrix

I recently observed a behavior in blender scripting which I do not understand. Can you help me understand what is happening in the following example?

Start blender, add a cube, go to scripting view and access the object's world matrix.

```
>>> obj = C.scene.objects["Cube"]
>>> obj.matrix_world
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

So far so good. Now move the object.

```
>>> obj.location = (1, 2, 3)
>>> obj.matrix_world
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Still everything okay. Now press `CTRL+Z` to undo setting the location and print matrix_world again.

```
>>> obj.matrix_world
Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

The `matrix_world` still has the same value as before undoing! Why is this happening?

I expected to see the identity matrix again, as the object in the 3d view moves to the origin. At first I thought it has to do with some missing scene updates, however, adding `C.scene.update()` anywhere does not change the output. It seems to me that the variable `obj` refers to a broken object after undoing.

The output is correct if I call `C.scene.objects["Cube"].matrix_world` instead of `obj.matrix_world`. Does this mean that I must never store objects in a python variable, because they can be broken at any time?

Edit: I am using blender 2.79b.

Edit 2:

The following may help to understand the problem:

```
>>> obj = C.scene.objects["Cube"]
>>> obj.location = (1, 2, 3)  # object moves as expected
>>> [press CTRL+Z]
>>> obj.location = (1, 2, 3)  # nothing happens?!
```

If I now move the object in the user perspective and simply type `>>> obj` in the console, blender crashes.

Comment: yep, seems like the variable obj is "referenced before asignament" y presume. if you do: obj = C.scene.objects["Cube"] again after modifyed the object you have not that isue. I tryed apply loc, rot, scale but it still crashes if you dont reasign obj. dont know why, but i think blender reference its object.data (loc,rot,meshes, vertex, etc) from the matrix. by modifing these values the objects "gets broken" because the var obj points to a matarix which does not exist anymore. i might be wrong, if the case someone please correct me.

Comment: You may try by using "bpy.context.object" what kind of means the object selected, dot .matrix_world istead of obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"] or C.scene.objects["Cube"] this way i didnt tryed but may be keeps track of whats doing.

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere? I would really like to know if this is only a bug or if blender has a rule like _undo invalidates all object variables_ or _you must not use object variables after undo_.

Comment: sorry, I dont know. I can keep guessing on whats going on. But im not a blender developer. So i dont know what [ctrl]+[z] does or how. I think the matrix gets conveted to Vectors of compex numbers, but are initially floats. it may be what makes blender to crash. But i dont know. Goog luck :D